# What is the correct method to determine if a system user exists locally on windows?

Tags: python-3.x, windows

I am working on an authentication system for a local server [jupyterhub](https://jupyter.org/hub) that relies on OAuth protocol. Additionally, it creates a local system user on windows, in case it does not exist.
What is the correct way to check whether a user exists on windows platforms using python?
This would include cases in which the system uses LDAP authentication and the user logged in the machine at least once.

I am looking for the correct windows alternative to the unix-like:

```py
import pwd
try:
   pwd.getpwnam(user.name)
except Exception as e:
   print(repr(e))
```

My current solution is to check for the existence of the `f"os.environ["SystemDrive"]\Users\{username}"` folder. Side question, is there any drawback with the current method?

Comment: With pywin32 installed, call `win32net.NetUserGetInfo(None, username, 0)`. This raises `win32net.error` if the call fails. Specifically if the user isn't found, `e.winerror == NERR_UserNotFound`. pywin32 's `winerror` module lacks the error codes from lmerr.h, so we have to hard code `NERR_UserNotFound = 2221`.

Comment: I might have oversimplified the question. The problem with this approach is that if the system uses LDAP authentication, the above would fail. I'll edit the question specifying that, my interest is in knowing both if the user exists locally or if it exists in a directory and logged in at least once.

Comment: Okay, I thought you were looking for a local account. AFAIK, there's no problem creating a local account with a given name if someone with the same name logged on with a domain account. I think Windows will just create a profile directory named "username.local". Vice versa if the domain account logs on when a local user account with the same name exists already, the domain user's profile directory is "username.<domain name>", and it can even start adding numbered suffixes such as ".001".

Comment: Anyway, take a look at "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList". Profiles are listed in subkeys named for the account SID string. You can convert the string SID to an SID (`win32security.ConvertStringSidToSid`) and lookup the account name, domain, and type (`win32security.LookupAccountSid`).

Comment: So I feel like this the drawback of looking for a C:\Users\X directory is that the user may indeed exist, but not have a folder (yet). For example, I have a situation where I have a local account "X" which does NOT have a C:\Users\"X" directory (I am logged in as a domain user so there is a C:\Users\"domain_user_name" folder though). Some helpful commands to run: `net user` - yields all local users, or via PowerShell `Get-LocalUser username-you-want`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution to checking if a local Windows user exists using python:

```
import subprocess
def local_user_exists_windows(username):
   r = subprocess.run("net user",stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
   #look for username in the output. Return carriage followed by line break followed by name, then space
   return f"\\r\\n{username.lower()} " in str(r.stdout).lower()
```

Alternative is to use a regular expression to find username match (^ is regex for beginning of line if used in conjunction with multiline, \b for word boundary):

```
import re
re.findall(rf"^{username}\b", out,flags=re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE)
```

Note that the `\b` could be replaced with `\s+` meaning a space character one or more times and yield similar results. The function above will return True if given user name is an exact match with local username on Windows.

Again, my reason for this solution is there might be drawback to checking whether the path `f"os.environ["SystemDrive"]\Users\{username}"` exists. For example, I have a case where a Local User (e.g,`local_username`) exists via the `net user` command or via looking at "Local Users and Groups" control panel, but there is no `C:\Users\local_user_name` folder. One reason for this I can think of off the top of my head is perhaps the user switched from logging in as a Local User to using a Domain Account, and their User folder was deleted to save space, so the User exists, but the folder does not, etc.)

The call to `net user` gets local users - and the output looks something like this:

```
User accounts for \\SOME-WINDOWS-COMPUTER
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SomeUser                 Administrator            DefaultAccount
Guest                    local_admin              WDAGUtilityAccount
```

Notice how the `SomeUser` in this example is preceded by a \r\n followed by multiple spaces, hence looking for a username string inside this string could yield a false positive if the string you are searching is contained inside another string.

The solution above works for me, but has been tested all of ten minutes, and there might be some other simpler or more pythonic way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

This response is a comment to the subprocess(“net user”) answer as I can’t comment. I’m becoming more interested in solving this more broadly on window. To address the question of “is there a more Pythonic way?” I think is there was consensus on the the pwd standard module would support windows. I’m busy getting jupyterhub  and Jupyter-collab working on windows 10 and facing similar challenges. I’m going to try net user too.